# Swift compiler struggles with this expression

Tags: swift, xcode

**EDIT**

The source of the issue seems to be the use of .lowercased() to return a lower case string. Adding this to any line seems to result in a 40-60ms compile time.

---

In an effort to speed up my compile times I've added the "-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies" flag detailed [here](https://irace.me/swift-profiling) as well as following the optimisation tips [here](https://hackernoon.com/speed-up-swift-compile-time-6f62d86f85e6)

The compiler seems to struggle with filter functions for example this:

```
    // Filter by search term
    if self.searchController.isActive {
        filteredManualTasksArray = self.filteredManualTasksArray.filter() {
            let taskName:String = $0.bmTaskName!.lowercased()
            let searchText:String = searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()
            return taskName.contains(searchText)
        }
    }
```

Result in this warning:

Expression took 51ms to type-check (limit: 50ms)

The variable filteredManualTasksArray is declared elsewhere as:

```
var filteredManualTasksArray:[BMTask]!
```

So all variables are explicitly typed as far as I can tell. Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

**Edit**: I've tried a couple of approaches that seem to make no difference

1) combining the three lines into one:

```
return $0.bmTaskName!.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased())
```

2) Specifying the filter type:

filteredManualTasksArray = self.filteredManualTasksArray.filter { **(task: BMTask) -> Bool** in

**Edit 2**

This line:

```
let searchText:String = searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()
```

Seems to be the cause of the issue - it take 38ms to type check. Any ideas how I can improve this?

Comment: Why do you evaluate  searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased() for each loop step ? Can't you evaluate it before ? So you won't need to keep the reference on searchController any longer

Comment: @CZ54 this is a good point and is moving things in the right direction. Please see response below.

Answer (score 2):

You could move the `let searchText` line out of the filter function:

```
if self.searchController.isActive {
    let searchText:String = searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()
    filteredManualTasksArray = self.filteredManualTasksArray.filter() {
        let taskName:String = $0.bmTaskName!.lowercased()
        return taskName.contains(searchText)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good point and will improve performance at run time (though not necessarily compilation time). Interestingly when I do this the line "let searchText:String = searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()" seems to be causing the delay - it takes 38ms to type-check

Comment: @Derek maybe try to unwrap the text in your if statement. Like if text = searchController.searchBar.text {} it will help compiler I move from String! to String

Comment: @CZ54 That doesn't affect the compile time but has narrowed down the problem. It seems to be the use of .lowercased(). Adding that to any line results in a 40-60ms compile time